# Turtle crashes unexpectantly during runtime

Tags: python

I added a new segment of code and now when I run my program turtle graphics crashes. I am not getting a runtime error in idle though so I am not sure what to change to fix it

The crash just started occurring when I implemented gotoFire() function. I can't remove it though because it is crucial to the operations of this program!

```
import turtle
import math
NUMBER_OF_LICENSES=10

def goodbyeMessage():
    print("Thank you for using the program!")

def getInfo():
    fire_Direction=math.radians(float(input("Please input the angle in degrees of the fire quickly!")))
    fire_Distance=float(input("Please input the distance of the fire ~VERY~ quickly (input a number between 1 and 5)"))
    return fire_Direction,fire_Distance


def announceDirections(horizontolDirection,verticalDirection):

    sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom=[]

    if horizontolDirection < 0:
        print("The fire is %d streets to the west of the firehouse!" %horizontolDirection)
        sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom += 'west'
    elif horizontolDirection > 0:
        print("The fire is %d streets to the east of the firehouse!" %horizontolDirection)
        sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom += 'east'
    else:
        sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom += 'void'

    if verticalDirection < 0:
        print("The fire is %d streets to the south of the firehouse!" %verticalDirection)
        sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom += 'south'
    elif verticalDirection > 0:
        print("The fire is %d streets to the north of the firehouse!" %verticalDirection)
        sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom += 'north'
    else:
        pass

    if verticalDirection == 0 and horizontolDirection == 0:
        print("The firehouse is on fire!")
        sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom += 'void' + 'void'

    return sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom

def gotoFire(horizontolDirection,verticalDirection,sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom):



    if sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom[0] == "east":
        turtle.forward(300)
        turtle.right(90)


    elif sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom[0] == "west":
        turtle.forward(200)
        turtle.right(90)

    else:
        pass

    if sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom[1] == "north":
        turtle.forward(200)

    elif sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom[1] == "south":
        turtle.forward(300)

    else:
        pass





def giveDirection(fire_Direction,fire_Distance):
    horizontolDirection = int(abs(round(fire_Distance * (math.cos(fire_Direction)))))
    verticalDirection = int(abs(round(fire_Distance * (math.sin(fire_Direction)))))
    sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom = announceDirections(horizontolDirection,verticalDirection)

    gotoFire(horizontolDirection,verticalDirection,sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom)



    return horizontolDirection, verticalDirection



def reportFire():

    fire_Direction,fire_Distance=getInfo()
    horizontolDirection,verticalDirection = giveDirection(fire_Direction,fire_Distance)



def drawHorizontal():
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(-300)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(300)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    for i in range(5):
        turtle.forward(500)
        turtle.forward(-500)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.forward(500)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(500)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(500)
    turtle.left(180)

def drawVertical():
    for i in range(5):
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.right(90)
            turtle.forward(500)
            turtle.forward(-500)
            turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(-500) #Back to upper left corner which will be main drawing control point

def drawFireStation():
    #From main drawing control point
    turtle.penup()
    #225 instead of 250 so firestation circle is centered in middle of grid
    turtle.forward(225)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(25)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(-250)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(-225)
def drawGrid():
    turtle.showturtle()
    turtle.speed(0)
    drawHorizontal()
    drawVertical()
    drawFireStation()



def main():
    drawGrid()
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_LICENSES):
        reportFire()
    goodbyeMessage()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a list of characters to the `sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom` argument of `gotoFire`

eg:

```
['v', 'o', 'i', 'd', 'n', 'o', 'r', 't', 'h']
```

This doesn't seem to be correct. I don't think your program is crashing. It's just not doing anything because the `if` conditions are all `False`

Looking back we see that the bad data seems to come from `announceDirections`. Because you are trying to add strings to a list.

```
>>> sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom=[]
>>> sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom += 'west'
>>> sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom
['w', 'e', 's', 't']
```

You probably should be using `sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom.append('west')` etc. instead

```
>>> sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom=[]
>>> sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom.append('west')
>>> sideOfFireHouseToLeaveFrom
['west']
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks again Gnibbler!